# How to get Debian RAID 1 preseed to populate EFI partitions on both disks?

Tags: debian, raid, uefi, preseed

Most similar question I found: [Ubuntu software raid on efi, how to boot off second drive?](https://serverfault.com/q/411249/313521)

My situation is, I have a working preseed file for Debian installation that will configure my NVMe drives to software RAID 1.  Both disks will even get an efi partition (/dev/nvme0n1p1 and /dev/nvme1n1p1).  However, the second disk's partition will not be populated so is not actually bootable if the first disk fails.

The point of RAID 1 is for disk failure scenarios.  If I can't boot off the second disk, that's sort of useless to me.

I have figured out a workaround where in the installation finish script I can run:

```
if [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && [ -d /boot/efi/EFI ] && [ -e /dev/nvme1n1p1 ]; then
    mkdir /mnt/efi-disk2
    mount /dev/nvme1n1p1 /mnt/efi-disk2 && cp -narv /boot/efi/EFI /mnt/efi-disk2/
    umount /mnt/efi-disk2
    rmdir /mnt/efi-disk2
fi
```

This works; however, possibly I've missed a better/easier way as this seems like basic core functionality that should be part of the installer.

Is there a way to make this happen during installation directly, e.g. using another preseed command or partman option that I've missed?

Relevant portions of preseed:

```
d-i mdadm/boot_degraded boolean false

d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-md/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-md/confirm_nooverwrite  boolean true

d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true

d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/nvme1n1
d-i partman-auto/method string raid
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select myrecipe

d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string 100%
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string vg00

d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

d-i partman/choose_partition select Finish partitioning and write changes to disk

d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true

d-i partman-basicfilesystems/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/default_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/default_label string gpt
d-i partman/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman/default_label string gpt

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
myrecipe :: \
    1024 1 1024 free \
            $iflabel{ gpt } \
            method{ efi } \
            format{ } \
        . \
    1024 0 -1 raid \
            $lvmignore{ } \
            $primary{ } \
            method{ raid } \
            format{ } \
        . \
    20480 0 20480 ext4 \
            $defaultignore{ } \
            $lvmok{ } \
            lv_name{ lv_root } \
            method{ format } \
            format{ } \
            use_filesystem{ } \
            filesystem{ ext4 } \
            mountpoint{ / } \
        . \
    20480 0 20480 ext4 \
            $defaultignore{ } \
            $lvmok{ } \
            lv_name{ lv_var } \
            method{ format } \
            format{ } \
            use_filesystem{ } \
            filesystem{ ext4 } \
            mountpoint{ /var } \
        . \
    1024 0 1024 swap \
            $defaultignore{ } \
            $lvmok{ } \
            lv_name{ lv_swap } \
            method{ swap } \
            format{ } \
        . \
    1024 0 1024 ext4 \
            $defaultignore{ } \
            $lvmok{ } \
            lv_name{ lv_tmp } \
            method{ format } \
            format{ } \
            use_filesystem{ } \
            filesystem{ ext4 } \
            mountpoint{ /tmp } \
        .

d-i partman-auto-raid/recipe string \
    1 2 0 lvm - /dev/nvme0n1p2#/dev/nvme1n1p2 \
        .

d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly let me thank you for your Preseed. This saved my butt! Its really hard to find a working example for Raid + LVM.

So to answer your question:
EFI standard does not include raid. Your way of copying this stuff the the second EFI partition is the only way i know of and also use.

However you can automate this maybe with a script in grub, so whenever grub gets updated at the end you can copy it over. eg: /etc/grub.d/99_copy_efi i still need to test this tho as i got other pressing matters at the moment.

Comment: Sounds good.  I no longer manage that same infrastructure, but yeah, pay it forward by documenting the working setup as an answer here if you get it working.  :)